# Coordinate Transformation (LL + Elevation to WGS84)

Tags: coordinate-systems, wgs84

I'm currently working on a 3D visualization project, and I came across an issue that I noticed we've been doing in a hackish way.

I'm not too experienced with the WGS84 system itself, and I was wondering if there was a "correct" way to convert a LL point into the WGS coordinate, given a specific value of elevation above the Earth's orbit.

How we're doing it now is doing the usual conversion from LL to WGS84, then taking the unit vector of that, and multiplying it by the sum of the elevation and the Earth's radius. This doesn't seem like the most efficient method, and I'm wondering if there's a more accepted way to make that conversion.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do here.  Are you saying that you're trying to convert LatLong to WGS 84 at elevations that are substantially different from the Earth's surface?

Comment: Chris: That's exactly right. I know WGS84 is mainly for points on the surface, but WGS84 is our internal coordinate system. Say, if I want to draw a sheet 5000m above the earth's surface, I need to convert the corners (and internal points, it curves) to WGS84.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many projection libraries, such as [Proj.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) and libraries using it like [GDAL/OGR](http://gdal.org/) will allow you to specify an elevation.

The [EPSG](http://www.epsg.org/) project has a database that lists the "proper" way to implement this, for nearly every projection out there, including WGS84 in geographic and projected coordinate systems.  It is a freely available database (although in MS Access format).

Comment: http://n2.nabble.com/WGS84-Lat-Lon-to-XYZ-convercion-td2063901.html

Thanks, the PROJ.4 library is a great example of something we could use.